# Symfony2 - Inheritance - repository find method

Tags: symfony, inheritance, doctrine-orm

I have entities

```
<?php

namespace Proj\Bundle\MyBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

/**
 * ClassTop
 *
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Proj\Bundle\MyBundle\Repository\ClassTopRepository")
 * @ORM\InheritanceType("SINGLE_TABLE")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorColumn(name="aVal", type="string")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorMap({ "ValOne" = "ClassSubOne", "ValTwo" = "ClassSubTwo", "ValThree" = "ClassSubThree" })
 * 
 */
class ClassTop
{
    .....
}

class ClassSubOne extends ClassTop
{
    ....
}

class ClassSubTwo extends ClassTop
{
    ....
}

class ClassSubThree extends ClassTop
{
    ....
}
```

My problem is when I call the `find()` (or `findOneBy`, `findAll`, etc) method, I have an Oracle error.

```
$entityManager->getRepository('ProjMyBundle:ClassSubOne')->findAll()
```

In the query I have

```
SELECT field, field2 FROM CLASSTOP WHERE aVAL IN ()
```

The discriminator value `"ValOne"` is not mapping and not passed in Doctrine.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to repository classes for the subclasses not the top one. You treat your subclasses as full defined classes and that's all. Then when you need to query for your entities you don't go for the top entity but the subclasses. I don't know if I made myself clear here!

In your case:

```
@ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="path\to\your\repository")
```

The repository line goes for the subclasses not the top superclass. so you do

```
/**
 *
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="path\to\your\ClassSubOneRepository")
 */
class ClassSubOne extends ClassTop
{
    ...
}
```

instead of

```
/**
 *
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Proj\Bundle\MyBundle\Repository\ClassTopRepository")
 */
class ClassTop
{
    ...
}
```